# Python Flask - repeatedly call code every 30 seconds

Tags: flask, timer, plotly

I've created a Python Flask server which makes an SQL query to a database and plots the result to a Plot.ly chart. I now want to use Plotly's streaming feature and have my chart update every x amount of seconds (undecided on frequency for now) but this will require the database to be queried for each update. Is there a way using Flask where I can call my queries using PyathenaJDBC at a certain interval?

Comment: Web servers are for responding to HTTP requests in a request/response cycle... you need to use something like a cron scheduler, AWS CloudWatch events or jenkins to run scheduled tasks... any web framework would be the wrong choice.

Comment: The reason for the downvote is unclear to me. A comment should have been left.